# Get rows from nth date of current month and upto next nth date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to fetch the rows having date from nth date of current month to nth date of next month or nth date of previous month to nth date of current month and so on..

Example:
I need to get all those rows which are between 5th of current month up to 5th of next month or form 5th of previous month to 5th of current month and similarly I want to go deeper as much as I want.

Is this kind of sql query is possible? if so then how can we achieve this?

Table Structure:

Table: transactions

```
-----------------------------------------
| id  | amount   |       timestamp      |
-----------------------------------------
| 1   |    200   |  2016-11-26 18:49:14 |
-----------------------------------------
| 2   |    300   |  2016-12-14 18:49:14 |
-----------------------------------------
| 34  |   232    |  2016-10-12 18:49:14 |
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? What does you table structure look like?

Comment: showing (table structure and) effort would help tremendously

Comment: Table structure is added.

Comment: here is a hint -- you can use features of sql to extract the month.  you can also filter rows using the where clause.  You should be able to answer this question after taking an intro sql class or reading an intro sql book.

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, amount, date
from tbl_1
where to_char(date,'YY/MM/DD') between '16/10/05' and '16/11/05';
```

Basic SQL, is that what you want?